# Does anyone know if it's possible to put your Django Heroku apps onto App Store/Google Play?

Tags: django, heroku, google-play, app-store

I have several apps that i've written in Django and host on Heroku. The website address works great but if people want to use my app on their mobile device i have to instruct them to visit the website then click Add to Home Screen so an app icon appears on their phone. Is there a better way of doing this so they can just add the app from say the App Store/Google Play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can add your [PWA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps) (progressive web apps) to Google PlayStore. There is detailed [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/pwa-in-play) about this.

But in case of App Store Apple doesn't supports to put PWA on App Store. But there are different ways to achieve this [PWABuilder](https://www.pwabuilder.com/) is one among them. And also that doesn't guarantee that your app will be accepted into Apple’s App Store. In 2019, Apple released [new guidelines for HTML5 apps](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09062019b) in the App Store. The new guidelines appear to forbid certain kinds of web apps (e.g. gambling, lotteries, etc.) from the iOS App Store.